# One million records Insert

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, eloquent

How to insert a million records into the database so that the system does not hang, and then twist the message that the page does not respond

```php
$rangeNumber = collect(range($validatedDate['from'], $validatedDate['to']));
$collectData = [];

foreach ($rangeNumber as $number){
$collectData [] = [
    'receive_uuid' => $receiveUUID,
    'region_id' => $regionId,
    'office_id' => $officeId,
    'number' => $prefix.str_pad($number, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
    'description' => '',
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
   ];
}

$dataCollection = collect($collectData)->chunk(10000);

foreach ($dataCollection as $key => $data){
    DB::table('blanks')->insert($data->toArray());
}

session()->flash('MsgSuccess', 'Success');
return $this->redirect(route('blanks'), true);
```

Comment: Can't you chunk the data so you don't have everything in memory? do 1k chunks. You will still have to do `n` insert queries this way, so chunk it to not have a million entries in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Laravel jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs), to handle all this in the backgrounds, so that you don't have to wait for the records to be insterted. Simple example:

```
php artisan make:job ProcessRecords
```

ProcessRecords class should look something like this:

```
class ProcessRecords implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    //Get passed data from controller
    public function __construct($rangeNumbers){
        $this->rangeNumbers = $rangeNumbers;
    }

    public function handle(): void{
        $collectData = [];
        
        foreach ($this->rangeNumbers as $number){
            $collectData [] = [
                'receive_uuid' => $receiveUUID,
                'region_id' => $regionId,
                'office_id' => $officeId,
                'number' => $prefix.str_pad($number, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'description' => '',
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ];
        }

        $dataCollection = collect($collectData)->chunk(10000);

        foreach ($dataCollection as $key => $data){
            DB::table('blanks')->insert($data->toArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can just dispatch this job from your controller:

```
$rangeNumbers = collect(range($validatedDate['from'], $validatedDate['to']));
ProcessRecords::dispatch($rangeNumbers);
session()->flash('MsgSuccess', 'Success');
return $this->redirect(route('blanks'), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely, this isn't a job to be done procedurally. Ideally, you'd want to run these types of jobs in the background using Jobs (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs).

This will run on a queue like Horizon (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/horizon) and process inserts in the background, consuming less memory and not making users wait for these inserts to process.

We can create one with:

```
php artisan make:job InsertBlanks
```

To produce a template that can do this processing in the background:

```php
class InsertBlanks implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public Collection $data,
    ) {}
 
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $data){
            DB::table('blanks')->insert($data->toArray());
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend one job PER chunk, allowing them to be processed in parallel and saving memory in the process. Ideally, to abstract this further we would create a parent job which performs data transformation as shown in your snippet and spawns child jobs for each generated chunk.

You can learn more about dispatching jobs here (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#dispatching-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the Queue jobs

What I would suggest is a [PHP generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php), Laravel already has [LazyCollection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#lazy-collections)

```php
LazyCollection::make(function () use(......) {
    foreach (range($validatedDate['from'], $validatedDate['to']) as $number) {
        yield [
            'receive_uuid' => $receiveUUID,
            'region_id' => $regionId,
            'office_id' => $officeId,
            'number' => $prefix . str_pad($number, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
            'description' => '',
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
    }
})
    ->chunk(1000)
    ->each(function ($data) {
        DB::table('blanks')->insert($data);
    });
```

**TIP:**
I would also recommend you to use [Laravel Benchmark](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#benchmarking)

or the old way

```
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    // your code

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    $echo $time
```